# ADF reprocess daily slice 3 times per day

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a complex ADF's pipeline with slice based scheduling, where slice = day.
Now it works like that:

Day1, Day2, Day3, ..., PreviousDay, **CurrentDay**

At 00:00 AM of CurrentDay it reprocess PreviousDay. So for Today i have calculated data for the previous day only.

I need to change the schedule to make it works like that:

1) slice size should be left the same = day

2) reprocessing for **CurrentDay** should be triggered 4 times per day to emulate results refresh (kinda running total)

The reason why i wanna leave the same slice size = 1 day, because it is a partition sizeof underlying tables. I dont wanna make them small as a few hours because it is meaningless for the current volume of data.

Cannot realize how to avoid change size of slice to a few hours and achive this goal. How to force reprocess current day? Any ideas will be helpfull for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to make 2 changes:

1. Set the availability to be StartOfInterval, thus running the CurrentDay instead of PreviousDay. [Dataset availability and policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-scheduling-and-execution#dataset-availability-and-policies)
2. Set the schedule of the activity to Hourly with frequency 8 (thereby running this 4 times per day) (See data-factory-scheduling-and-execution#specify-schedule-for-an-activity for more info) The activity and output should have matching slices, this can be fixed with the description below.

Since the slices of the input (Day:1) and activity (Hour:8) is different, you need to set two extra parameters in the activity for the input, to change the slice from 8 hours to 1 day, thus matching the input. The execution is based on the output slice. This is explained further here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-scheduling-and-execution#model-datasets-with-different-frequencies The Activity and output slice also have different slices and can be fixed with the same method.

Comment: Do i right understand it will work correctly only if Concurency = "1"

Comment: If Concurency > 1 then side effects are possible, because activity instances possibly will work on physically overlapped pieces of data.

Comment: Yes, concurrency should be 1, since you're running the same data in multiple slices, to avoid side effects. But it depends on the logic in your procedure processing the data, if it can handle multiple instances of it self on the same data, then higher concurrency won't be a problem.